# Face recognition is not installing in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition

It is showing `dlib` error and showing failed to compile
I have used

```
pip install face_recognition
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What's the error message when installing?

Comment: It showing dlib error

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
pip install face-recognition
```

The underscore should be a hyphen